# Save proxy credentials after clicking "never save this password"

Tags: windows, google-chrome, internet, proxy

I entered my proxy credentials in `Chrome` when I started surfing, I hit `Never save this password` by mistake, now every time I load a new website, Chrome asks me to enter those credentials again, how do I save them now to prevent this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You may achieve this by navigating to **settings** within chrome, click on **Manage saved password** under **Password and forms**. Or simply follow below;

- Open a new tab and type `chrome://settings/passwords` which will take you the passwords options in one go. Then remove the links which are listed under **never saved** column (shown in below image).

[image]

Comment: I'm in that window, I got the never stored, but I can't edit it

Comment: I'd say delete that part from the **Never saved** & re-login by closing/opening your chrome.

Comment: you're very welcome :)